# Reading special characters from dynamic source in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unicode

I am using a dynamic source to update my texts, it works perfect for normal character however for special characters like Chinese it only works if I directly put them in xaml file. It won't work if it is loaded dynamically.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefBtn}" x:Name="button_CreateElement" Content="{DynamicResource CMMsg_5171}"  Click="button_CreateElement_Click"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefBtn}" x:Name="button_DeleteElement" Content="删除" Click="button_DeleteElement_Click"/>
```

Here how it is rendered.

[image]

As you can see the dynamically loaded one is wrong.

Comment: why do you need to load them dynamically?

Comment: Because there are more than 10000 strings that a translator will have to translate and also there are different languages, so I cannot hardcode them.

Comment: We would need to see how your string resource is declared.  Also, check the encoding on the resource file, and in the xml header.

Comment: are you using mvvm?

Comment: This is how I do it in CLR and then load them based on the line they are on. gcroot<System::Windows::Controls::UserControl^> gLic;  gLic->Resources->MergedDictionaries->Add(gcnew MsgDict());

Comment: .NET strings *are* Unicode. Chnese characters are *not* special. Newlines, tabs etc are special. If you get any problems it's because you mixed up ASCII with Unicode somewhere, or loaded an ASCII file using the wrong codepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<Window ... >

<!-- 
<Window.Resources>
    <clr:String x:Key="CMMsg_5171">删除</clr:String>
</Window.Resources> 
-->

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource CMMsg_5171}" />
    <TextBlock Text="删除" />
</StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE:**

> "loading the strings from an external file. Would that work as well?"

Yes. I added a resource dictionary `ChineseTranslations.xaml` (you could have one for each language), by right-click on project, Add, Resource Dictionary...
Build Action was set to 'Content' and 'Copy Always'.

```
<ResourceDictionary ... xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" >

    <clr:String x:Key="CMMsg_5171">删除</clr:String>
    <!--more to come...-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I added this resource dictionary to the merged dictionaries in the following manner:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadTranslations();
}

private void LoadTranslations()
{
    string file = GetTranslationsFileForSelectedLanguage();

    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
        ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)reader.LoadAsync(stream);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
    }
}

private string GetTranslationsFileForSelectedLanguage()
{
    // todo: add selection logic for when we have more languages in the future
    return "ChineseTranslations.xaml";
}
```

Comment: I am loading the strings from an external file. Would that work as well? And how can I have it in different language so to say english? Right now I have different text files for each language that I load the strings from depending on what language user chooses.

Comment: Note that using hex codes also doesn't work for me and it shows the literal text rather than translating it when I use something like this instead of the chinese character. "\xE10F"

Comment: @VegaBrothers .NET strings *are* Unicode. Chinese aren't special. You are probably (certainly) loading an *ASCII* file using the wrong encoding. Post your code!

Comment: @VegaBrothers what is the *file's* encoding? How did you read it?

Comment: @vegabrothers In Xaml, or any XML language, you need to use `&#xE10F` instead of `\xE10F`.  Different language, different escaping rules.